# Why is "data" not a dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to parse JSON that I'm getting from an API using SwiftyJSON and it's giving me this error:
`Optional(Error Domain=SwiftyJSONErrorDomain Code=901 "Dictionary["data"] failure, It is not an dictionary" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Dictionary["data"] failure, It is not an dictionary})`

The JSON:

```
{
"status": 200,
"error": "",
"data": {
    "cursusses": [
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 1,
                "curNaam": "Lightroom Tips & Tricks",
                "catId": 1,
                "curInfo": "Praktische en korte Tips en Tricks om sneller en prettiger met Lightroom te kunnen werken.",
                "curThumbnail": "lr5-tips-en-tricks.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 2,
                "curNaam": "Lightroom Fotobewerkingen",
                "catId": 1,
                "curInfo": "Per video wordt er in deze cursus een nabewerking uitgevoerd op een foto. Een leerzame manier om te zien hoe je in de praktijk foto's kunt nabewerken terwijl je daarnaast veel praktische tips krijgt over het gebruik van Lightroom 5.",
                "curThumbnail": "lr5-bewerkingen.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 3,
                "curNaam": "Photoshop Fotobewerkingen",
                "catId": 2,
                "curInfo": "Per video wordt er in deze cursus een nabewerking uitgevoerd op een foto. Een leerzame manier om te zien hoe je in de praktijk foto's kunt nabewerken terwijl je daarnaast veel praktische tips krijgt over het gebruik van Photoshop.",
                "curThumbnail": "photoshop-cc.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 4,
                "curNaam": "Basiscursus Lightroom 5",
                "catId": 1,
                "curInfo": "Leer de basisvaardigheden voor het werken met Adobe Photoshop Lightroom. Over het werken met catalogussen, importeren, het selectieproces, de nabewerking en het exporteren.",
                "curThumbnail": "basiscursus-lightroom-5.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 5,
                "curNaam": "Photofacts Academy",
                "catId": 3,
                "curInfo": "Toelichting over het gebruiken van de Photofacts Academy website.",
                "curThumbnail": "photofacts-academy.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 6,
                "curNaam": "Lightroom 5 web module",
                "catId": 1,
                "curInfo": "Met de Lightroom web module kun je eenvoudig van je foto's een online galerij maken.",
                "curThumbnail": "lr5-web-intro.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "cursus": {
                "curId": 7,
                "curNaam": "Photoshop Tips & Tricks",
                "catId": 2,
                "curInfo": "Praktische tips voor het gebruik van Adobe Photoshop CC.",
                "curThumbnail": "photoshop-cc-splash.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I'm currently trying to use this block of code to parse the data, this function is called in the completionHandler of an Alamofire request:

```
func succesCurResponse(let response : Response<String, NSError>) {
    if let value = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(value)
        let error = json["error"].stringValue
        print(json["data"].error)
        if(error.isEmpty) {
            for(var i = 0; i < json["data"]["cursusses"].count; i++) {
                let name = json["data"]["cursusses"][i]["cursus"]["curNaam"].stringValue
                let id = json["data"]["cursusses"][i]["cursus"]["curId"].intValue
                let catId = json["data"]["cursusses"][i]["cursus"]["catId"].intValue
                let info = json["data"]["cursusses"][i]["cursus"]["curInfo"].stringValue
                let thumbnail = json["data"]["cursusses"][i]["cursus"]["curThumbnail"].stringValue
                let newCur = Cursus()
                newCur.ID = id
                newCur.name = name
                newCur.info = info
                newCur.thumbnail = thumbnail
            }
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try `let json = JSON(value) as! NSDictionary`?

Comment: It would be utterly helpful (for you when trying to understand the error, and for people trying to help you) to identify the line of error.

Comment: @aaisataev Swift gives a warning that it's an unrelated type so the cast will always fail

Comment: also, try to put some breakpoints there and quick view `json` to see what happened there. maybe you will need to cast `json["data"]` to a dictionary before starting the for-loop.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe It normally doesn't give a warning, it just skips the for-block completely, I added a `print(json["data"].error)` to my code so I could see the error.

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier Thanks for the suggestion, I stored `json["data"]` in a variable and put a breakpoint on it. After stepping over it is empty except for a `NSError` which contains `unable to read data`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know Swift. But the following Objective-C code will help you to  resolve your issue.

**Objective-C :**

```
NSArray *cursussesArray = json[@"cursusses"];

for (NSDictionary *singlecursusseDict in cursussesArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", singlecursusseDict);

    NSDictionary *cursus = singlecursusseDict[@"cursus"];
}
```

I give a try in **Swift**

```
let cursussesArray:NSArray = json[“cursusses”]

for singlecursusseDict: NSDictionary in cursussesArray {
    print(singlecursusseDict)
    cursusDict: NSDictionary = json[“cursus”]
    print(cursusDict)
}
```

Comment: The error is on `data`, not `cursusses` and the object can't be cast to `NSArray` so this does not work.